# How to Edit text function in React Hooks CRUD app? example note taking / todo app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm learning React with Hooks and context. Learning by making a simple CRUD app. I have functions that allow me to ADD notes, DELETE notes, Filter if important, Toggle importance in some Context. So far so good.
However I'm stuck on how I would be able to edit my note. I've searched online and every react hooks CRUD tutorial seems to just be add and delete.

My functions for a CRUD note taking app below.

```js
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import uuid from 'uuid/v1';

export const NotesContext = createContext();

const NotesContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
  const [showAll, setShowAll] = useState(true);

  const notesToShow = showAll ? notes : notes.filter((note) => note.important);

  //CRUD operations

  // Create
  const addNote = (content) => {
    setNotes([
      ...notes,
      {
        content,
        id: uuid(),
        important: false
      }
    ]);
  };

  // Update
  const toggleImportance = (noteId) => {
    const updatedNotes = notes.map((note) =>
      note.id === noteId ? { ...note, important: !note.important } : note
    );
    setNotes(updatedNotes);
  };

  // Delete
  const removeNote = (id) => {
    setNotes(notes.filter((note) => note.id !== id));
  };

  // Get any notes stored in local storage
  useEffect(() => {
    const data = localStorage.getItem('notes');
    if (data) {
      setNotes(JSON.parse(data));
    }
  }, []);

  // save notes to local storage
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('notes', JSON.stringify(notes));
  }, [notes]);

  return (
    <NotesContext.Provider
      value={{
        addNote,
        removeNote,
        notes,
        showAll,
        setShowAll,
        notesToShow,
        toggleImportance
      }}>
      {props.children}
    </NotesContext.Provider>
  );
};
export default NotesContextProvider;
```

I'm hoping to have an onClick on an edit button on my note/todo and it'll allow me to update the note/todo.

Thanks any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: You are right . Use uuid to find your note